# Deleting empty records from a table (Access 2013)

Tags: ms-access, vba, ms-access-2013

Theere is a *Tasks* table and a *Contacts* table where the initial data is stored

Comment: what do you mean by **it will not be able to delete the previous record from EmployeestoTasks**

Comment: If there are other employees with tasks then you shouldn't be deleting the the EmployeesToTask record.  However, if you're testing for that already, then the WHERE should be `WHERE AssignedTo= ""` right?  How is that AssignedTo field being updated?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Below statement deletes all records in EmployeestoTasks having a task that does not exist in Tasks:

```
DELETE
FROM EmployeestoTasks
WHERE NOT EXISTS
(
SELECT '1'
FROM Tasks
WHERE Tasks.Title = EmployeestoTasks.Task
)
```

Comment: As far as I know, you can use whatever you prefer. I just tend to use `SELECT '1'`.